# Flutter - Transform flutter bloc event to add debounce

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart, flutter-bloc

I am trying to make an Infinite list using flutter bloc.

I have taken reference from here: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/926029cae2d7614d38b5a9a8952e36bb59054b02/examples/github_search/common_github_search/lib/src/github_search_bloc/github_search_bloc.dart#L15

According to this post, to add a delay between two events so that api doesn't get spammed, you need to override `transformEvents` and add debounce to events like this:

```
@override
  Stream<GithubSearchState> transformEvents(
    Stream<GithubSearchEvent> events,
    Stream<GithubSearchState> Function(GithubSearchEvent event) next,
  ) {
    return (events as Observable<GithubSearchEvent>)
        .debounceTime(
          Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        )
        .switchMap(next);
  }
```

Problem I am facing is that the Observable has been deprecated by RxDart and I am not sure how to accomplish the above requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
@override
  Stream<Transition< GithubSearchEvent, GithubSearchState >> transformEvents(
      Stream< GithubSearchEvent > events, transitionFn) {
    return events
        .debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 300))
        .switchMap((transitionFn));
  }
```

Comment: This may skip over events if they are sent too frequent?

Comment: `EventTransformer` is deprecated, how can we implement this with `onEvent`?

Comment: @Hamed you can pass the `transformer` to the `on` function. There are a few predefined in the `bloc_concurrency` package but to debounce you have to pass the function yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70834818/10121512

Answer (score 22):

Since `bloc` 8.0.0 the syntax changed and you need to pass it as a transformer to the `on` function. Apart from the debouncing you should think about [concurrency](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_concurrency). To combine sequential processing with a debounce, you can provide the following function:

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
//...

    on<GithubSearchEvent>(
      (event, emit) {},
      transformer: (events, mapper) {
        return events.debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 300)).asyncExpand(mapper);
      },
    );
```

You can create a reusable transformer as a top-level function like this:

```dart
EventTransformer<Event> debounceSequential<Event>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) => events.debounceTime(duration).asyncExpand(mapper);
}
```

and use it like this:

```dart
    on<GithubSearchEvent>(
      (event, emit) {},
      transformer: debounceSequential(const Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
    );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70834818/10121512

Comment: Wonderful response!

Answer (score 7):

I cannt add comment to @user2220771 cause my reputation is too low.

This will not work:

```
EventTransformer<Event> debounceTransformer<Event>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) => events.debounceTime(duration);
}
```

you have to switch map as:

```
EventTransformer<Event> debounceTransformer<Event>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return events.debounceTime(duration).switchMap(mapper);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had a similar issue and I could solve it by adding the below imports**

```
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
```

Then we can provide a custom EventTransformer to change the way the Bloc processes incoming events.

```
EventTransformer<T> debounce<T>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) => events.debounceTime(duration).flatMap(mapper);
}
```

Now we would probably want to debounce the requests to the backend to avoid getting rate-limited and cut down on cost/load on the backend.

```
CounterBloc() : super(0) {
  on<Increment>(
    (event, emit) => emit(state + 1),
    /// Apply the custom `EventTransformer` to the `EventHandler`.
    transformer: debounce(const Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
  );
}
```

Note: I was using `flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1`